# how to automate the configuration of an index pattern in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Is it possible to automate the configuration of an index pattern in kibana? Either via some settings file or perhaps a rest api. After installation it's possible to do it manually.

Comment: I'd also like to be able to do this.. would be great when using vagrant, or in fresh installs

Answer (score 3):

Kibana 5.x exposes such an API to manage index patterns.

To create index pattern one can issue below command to kibana access url (just edit the kibana endpoint, index-name and timestamp variables to match your needs):

```
curl <kibana-endpoint>/es_admin/.kibana/index-pattern/<index-name>/_create\
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
    -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"\
    -H "kbn-xsrf: <index-name>"\
    --data-binary '{"title":"${<index-name>}","timeFieldName":"<timestamp-field>"}' -w "\n"
```

For instance if kibana is under localhost:5601 and index-name is alert (alert_time is timestamp field) then command:

```
curl localhost:5601/es_admin/.kibana/index-pattern/alert/_create\ 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
    -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"\
    -H "kbn-xsrf: alert"\
    --data-binary '{"title":"alert","timeFieldName":"alert_time"}'  -w "\n"
```

Similarly, one can define default index pattern using below API for the example:

```
curl localhost:5601/api/kibana/settings/defaultIndex\
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
    -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"\
    -H "kbn-xsrf: alert"\
    -H "Connection: keep-alive"\
    --data-binary "{\"value\":\"alert\"}" -w "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

At present this is not possible. There is an issue at the Kibana github repo which schedules an Index pattern creation API for the 4.5.0 release. 
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3709