# elk kibana how to set default index pattern

Tags: elastic-stack

I am using elk6.0. Now I can create index pattern from command line, like

```
curl -XPOST "http://${host}:9200/.kibana/doc/index-pattern:oauth-message" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "type" : "index-pattern",
  "index-pattern" : {
    "title": "oauth-message-*",
    "timeFieldName": "execution_time"
  }
}'
```

But I didn't find any way to specify default index pattern. I found an old post which is for 4.5.0 ([Programmatically set Kibana's default index pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871862/programmatically-set-kibanas-default-index-pattern)) . It didn't work on 6.0.0 any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on the kibana endpoint (port 5601):

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5601/api/kibana/settings/defaultIndex' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
    -H 'kbn-xsrf: name-of-the-default-index' \
    --data-binary '{\"value\":\"name-of-the-default-index\"}' -w '\n'
```